# Stretching of cell in XSL export of Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

For the vertical stretching of cell in XSL export I set to this cell parameter "Stretch with overflow", use the special xsl property `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>` and cover cells by frame element. All is fine in the main report. But there is problem in the subreports. Cells are not stretching. I have such a code:

`<detail>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="15" uuid="">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="subCell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{operator}!=null?$F{operator}:""]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="subCell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="80" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{casino}!=null?$F{casino}:""]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="subCell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="160" y="0" width="75" height="15" uuid="">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cabinet}!=null?$F{cabinet}:""]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="subCell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="235" y="0" width="80" height="15" uuid="">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box topPadding="1" bottomPadding="2"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{serial}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="subCell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="315" y="0" width="60" height="15" uuid="">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{soft}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement style="subCell" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="375" y="0" width="25" height="15" uuid="">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{isOnline}==true?"Yes":"No"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>`

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with this problem for a long time and AFAIK it is an XLS format issue and cannot be solved completely. There is a number of tricks you can try though, including these: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/844164/shrink-fit-property-when-exporting-excel

Comment: I have solved this problem. Your link helped me in it as catalyst of thinking. Thank you!

Comment: It was wrong way to set <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/> to all cells in the frame. In this case all cells can expand not at the size of biggest text but at the size of smallest text wherein cells with big texts  clips. Probably it is an Excel bug.   Right way is set this property for cell with big texts only.