# Jasper report, approach to create table

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to create the following table
[image: table to create]

Where:

- (V**x**) means that it's a variable retrieved from a JSON dataset ($F)
- Info**x** and SubInfo**x** means it's a resource field ($R)

Actually i tried the Table and CrossTable components but they seem to be used for presenting recurring data (like sales per months...).
What I also need it's that a line's size should dynamically change depending on the text size (coming from resource fields or variable fields).

Should i use rectangles component and lines component to obtain that result (which can be pretty long...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should use the `Stretch Type` property with the value `Relative to Tallest Object` and `Stretch With Overflow` with the value `true` set to all the fields in your `detail` band. You should also set the `Position Type` property to `float` for all the elements in the `detail` band and all the elements in all the bands **under** the `detail` band. This will allow report rows to stretch as necessary. Note that this might not entirely work for XLS and XLSX, see [Stretching of cell in XSL export of Jasper reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404289/stretching-of-cell-in-xsl-export-of-jasper-reports/31491685#31491685)

Comment: Thx :), this is what i needed, I also used the option "Print when detail overflow" in order to print the lines in the next page if some part of the table overflow in the next page. Of course each row has it's own frame.